# (FLUTTER) ontap ListView(return listTile()) with Streambuilder causing data for inheritance to be null?

Tags: listview, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, materialpageroute

Hi im trying to create simple realtime database using Streambuilder while returning a Listview.builder which in it is a ListTile. I wish to give the ListTile an ability to move to other dart. which, I managed to do however when im trying to pass the item it becomes **null** but when I try to print it, it prints in the terminal.

```
 class ListItemsDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _ListItemsDisplay();
      }
    }

    class _ListItemsDisplay extends State<ListItemsDisplay> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("posts").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Loading.."),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index)`enter code here` {
                      if (snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'] != null &&
                          snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'] != "" &&
                          snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'] != " ") {
                        print(
                            "MY ID: " + snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID);
                        return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']),
                            onTap: () {
                              if (snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'] != 

    null) {**//AS YOU CAN SEE HERE IM TRYING TO PASS the document id in DISPLAYITEM() CLASS**
    print("MY ITEM ID ""TAPPED"" IF NOT NULL: "+snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID);
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => DisplayItem(snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID)));
                              } else {
                                print("MY ITEM ID ""TAPPED"" IF NULL: "+snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID);
                              }
                            });
                      } else {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text("Missing title [REPORT TO ADMIN]"),
                        );
                      }
                    });
              }
            });
      }
    }
```

Here is my DisplayItem class.

```
class DisplayItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _myId;
  DisplayItem(this._myId);
  String getTitle(String myId) {
    if(myId.isNotEmpty && myId!=null) {
      Firestore.instance.collection("posts").document(myId).get().then((value) {
        if (value.data['title'].toString() != null &&
            value.data['title'].toString() != "" &&
            value.data['title'].toString() != " ")
          return value.data['title'].toString();
        else
          return "NONE FOUND";
      });
    }
    else
      return "HELLO";
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TITLE"),
    ),
    body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(getTitle(_myId)),
    ],
    ),
    ),
    );
    }
  }
```

Im trying to build a realtime database (firestore), in which the flutter will display list of item, upon click any item listed; it will redirect the user unto another dart file, in which that dart file will display more description of the item.

Here is the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building DisplayItem(dirty):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DisplayItem file:///D:/Programming/Flutter_Projects/flutter_study/lib/main.dart:64:59
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:298:10)
#3      DisplayItem.build (package:flutterstudy/Display.dart:31:7)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:28)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

HERE IS THE ID IM TRYING TO PASS
I/flutter (11339): MY NOT NULL ID: sc94LjZJz57t947YgTlp
```

WHEN I CLICK THIS ( DisplayItem file:///D:/Programming/Flutter_Projects/flutter_study/lib/main.dart:64:59)

IM REDIRECTED HERE:
builder: (context) => DisplayItem(snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID)));

```
HERE's WHAT HAPPENS:
as soon as I ran, I added a print method that will print document ID of items.
I/flutter (13386): MY ID: sc94LjZJz57t947YgTlp
I/flutter (13386): MY ID: xqbkvhVveYhr3YvgSGuE

Now I clicked any of the Item

IT Shows the **ERROR ON TERMINAL** then it displays the last method I added in onTap, which print method:
I/flutter (13386): MY ITEM ID TAPPED IF NOT NULL: sc94LjZJz57t947YgTlp
```

Comment: What value you get when list is tapped? `snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID`

Comment: Hi John, sorry I didnt updated asap. Anyway, if I didnt redirect or just use plain print(object) method. It display the ID ("sc94LjZJz57t947YgTlp"), However, soon as I go materialpageroute. It seems to give me an error.

Comment: I a bit confused now. Are you able to print `snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID`  when list is clicked?

Comment: Yes, Im able to print it and it works fine. I'll edit my posts that is shows im able to print the document ID.

Comment: try `Text(getTitle(widget._myId))`

Comment: Hi, John, It gave me a new error       
                                                                           
                                                                           
        Compiler message:
lib/Display.dart:31:21: Error: The getter 'widget' isn't defined for the class 'DisplayItem'.
 - 'DisplayItem' is from 'package:flutterstudy/Display.dart' ('lib/Display.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'widget'.
      Text(getTitle(widget._myId)),
                    ^^^^^^

Comment: try `Text(_myId)`.Do you get  exception ?

Comment: No, not at all. wow progress thanks, I think the error has something with the function.

Comment: Try to use ```title: Text("${snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']}"),```

Comment: ok, mean `id` not null. Possible `value.data['title'].toString()` is null then. Check the value by printing `value.data['title'].toString()` out.

Comment: I managed to pass the documentId inside display.dart, Now, im just trying to find out how I can use document id to gather datas of that id.

Comment: Hi John, so I did this and managed to retrieve the datas while using the inherited data (myId).

Comment: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("posts").document(_myId).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
          return Text(snapshot.data["title"]);
      })

Comment: So I managed to display it but another error is showing, it works but theres an error message?

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("title")

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///D:/Programming/Flutter_Projects/flutter_study/lib/Display.dart:17:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      DisplayItem.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterstudy/Display.dart:20:32)

Comment: print `snapshot.data`. What you get ?

Comment: print snapshot.data["title"], I get the document title where equals to _myid. both print method and new streambuilder method which I now use, displays the item; nevertheless error notification displays in the terminal??

Comment: Wait, scratch out the print method. The streambuilder works fine, print method does not. My print method displays this I/flutter (13386): TITLE ON DISPLAy: null

Comment: and after showing lists of error, it displays again                
                 I/flutter (13386): TITLE ON DISPLAy: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'

Comment: Do you know how to use `ConnectionState`? Display  `Text(snapshot.data["title"]` in `Connection.active` and you will be good to go.

Comment: hmmm, I'll get to it, thanks.

Comment: No problem.....

Answer (score 0):

Base from the logs, it seems that the String that's been provided to the Text widget is null. If there's a chance that the String can be null, a workaround for this is to assign a default String to the Text widget in case the String has yet to load. Use the "if null" (??) operator on the Widget to provide the default value.

```dart
Text(nullableString ?? 'Default String');
```

If `nullableString` is **null**, then 'Default String' will be used.

Then the reason why you're getting null on your Text Widget is that you're assigning a `Future` on `Text(getTitle(_myId))`. The function `getTitle()` doesn't return the String in an instant. One way of fetching the value before loading it on the Widget is with the use of a `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getTitle(_myId), // fetch the String
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    return Text(snapshot.data ?? 'Loading...');
  }
)
```